# ViewPager in a ScrollView with dynamic page heights

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-pageradapter

I've read many other SO answers but nothing seems to be what I want. What I want is a ViewPager inside a ScrollView with the heights of each page being appropriate for the content. Some of the more accepted answers on SO seem to have to take the max height of the children in the ViewPager but that leads for empty space.

WrapContentViewPager

```
public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {


public WrapContentViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrapContentViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = 0;
    View view = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        view = getChildAt(i);
        view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    if (height != 0) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, view));
}


/**
 * Determines the height of this view
 *
 * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @param view the base view with already measured height
 *
 * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureHeight(int measureSpec, View view) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // set the height from the base view if available
        if (view != null) {
            result = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            result = Math.min(result, specSize);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

The reason why this doesn't work is because if I go to the third page, which has a large height with 32 items in the list, then go back to the second page with only 3 items, there is a lot of empty space in the second page since it took the height of the third page as max.

I've tried WCViewPager library on GitHub at https://github.com/rnevet/WCViewPager and it doesn't work for me as well.

**Could someone guide me to a correct solution? I am using a ViewPager with just PagerAdapter, not FragmentPagerAdapter by the way.**

**UPDATE**

I figured out a better way to solve it.

`public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {

```
public WrapContentViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public WrapContentViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Unspecified means that the ViewPager is in a ScrollView WRAP_CONTENT.
    // At Most means that the ViewPager is not in a ScrollView WRAP_CONTENT.
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // super has to be called in the beginning so the child views can be initialized.
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int position = getCurrentItem();
        View child = this.findViewWithTag("view"+position);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }
    // super has to be called again so the new specs are treated as exact measurements
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}`

and in my `PagerAdapter` I changed the method `instantiateItem`

```
 @Override
public @NonNull Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, view, false);
    layout.setTag("view" + position);
}
```

This solution remeasures the height at the current page every time it is moved. `getChildAt(getCurrentItem())` gives different results so it's not reliable.

Comment: What's the problem of `WCViewPager`?

Comment: @HongDuan didn't show anything in the ViewPager. I might try again later on just to make sure though.

Comment: @HongDuan does not show my dynamic TableLayouts in each page at all. The sample given works with TextView but not dynamically generated I think.

Comment: Can you share the code about your dynamic TableLayouts?